# Ecommerce Tracking via Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a question regarding ecommerce tracking.

I wanted to track the products added from cart/removed from cart.

How can I track if a user adds multiple products to cart,or how can we add the details of a single product when we cannot decide which product user will click. And if a user can take different quantities, How can we assign quantities in a macro?

I found a JavaScript which goes like this:

```
function() {
    var ecommerceData = {
        'event': 'addToCart',
        'ecommerce': {
            'currencyCode': 'USD',
            'add': {
                'products': [{
                    'id': '122',
                    'name': 'Shirt',
                    'quantity': '2'
                }]
            }
        }
    };
    return ecommerceData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Multiple products:

```
function() {
    var ecommerceData = {
        'event': 'addToCart',
        'ecommerce': {
            'currencyCode': 'USD',
            'add': {
                'products': [
                    {
                        'id': '122',
                        'name': 'Shirt',
                        'quantity': 1 // integer type
                    },
                    {
                        'id': '125',
                        'name': 'Shirt with Coffe',
                        'quantity': {{Quantity}} // via macro in GTM
                    },
                    {
                        'id': '129',
                        'name': 'Coffee with cottage cheese',
                        'quantity': item.qty // via js variable/object
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    };
    return ecommerceData;
}
```

### Documentation:

GTM and Enhanced Ecommerce

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce

Field reference

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce

Comment: Thanks !!! I still have lil doubt.A user can click any product and add to cart ,so in case of this macro we are predefining.But  how can we decide before hand.

Comment: Use variables/macros in for all Enhanced Ecommerce parameters. You will have one script and each item added to cart will pass its data to this script.

Comment: Herr kreuz, I have implemented this code function trackAddToCart(){
  var ecommerceData = {
    'event':'addToCart',
    'ecommerce':{
      'add':{
        'products':[{
          'id':{{Product-ID}},
          'name':'${product.name}',
          'quantity':itemprop.qty
        }]
      }
    }
  };
  return ecommerceData;
}
         

but add to cart s not getting tracked.Can you please help me out

Comment: Do you have enabled ecommerce tracking in Google Tag Manager -> Tab -> Enable Enhanced Ecommerce? AND do you set up an event Firing Rule to track this?

Comment: yes Herr Kreuz, I have enabled enhanced ecommerce and firing rule also i have set .